# Compiled MuPDF library integration in android project

Tags: pdf-rendering

I have compiled mupdf library but when I integrate it in my existing android project to render the PDF it give me the following error :

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

I have followed the following steps for integration :

Steps are explained here :
http://pastebin.com/YzHUhzE7

When i change the package name in mupdf test project then the native code get modified and the above expiation arises . So if any one knows how to integrate MuPDF compiled in my project .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I have integrated compiled mupdf library into my project .

Following steps  I have followed :
 after importing library into my project run the ndk-build on the jni. It will build the library. 
 Now the ExpetionInitializationError is solved.
 Now the application is running on the device.

Comment: just one question, did you make it compatible with all kinds of architectures ?

Comment: Yes I made it compatiable to all architcture by setting api level to 3  while compiling

Comment: hello, could you please give a working copy of the library in a zip? 
I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in this link http://www.chinabtp.com/android-pdf-viewer-library-or-mupdf-library-tutorials/

Here is the instruction:

```
Building a MuPDF lib on windows with Cygwin and android-ndk

Download MuPDF 1.3 Source from https://code.google.com/p/mupdf/downloads/list unzip to folder c:/mupdf-1.3-source

Install Cygwin: Download and run Run setup-x86.exe from http://cygwin.com/install.html when installing cygwin, make sure you selected make packages and C++ compilers

Make generate. open cygwin terminal, run

cd /cygdrive/
cd c/mupdf-1.3-source
make generate

Install android-ndk: download android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86.zip and unzip it to

c:/android-ndk-r9d

Build mupdf lib: on windows cmd console:

    preparation:

    cd c:/mupdf-1.3-source/platform/android
    copy local.properties.sample local.properties

    edit local.properties, uncomment

    #sdk.dir=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk

    and change to

    sdk.dir=REAL andforid-sdk Folder

    build: while still on c:/mupdf-1.3-source/platform/android, run:

    /android-ndk-r9d/ndk-build

    Upon the completion of the build, a folder named libs will be created under

    c:/mupdf-1.3-source/platform/android

Create android apk. Open eclipse, create a new android project from existing code, browse to c:/mupdf-1.3-source/platform/android, now you can create a mupdf apk.
```